# Why does Titan have this limitation?

Tags: titan

It says [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.3/limitations.html):

> The definition of an edge label, property key, or vertex label cannot
>   be changed once its committed into the graph.

In contrast SQL Server, which is what I'd normally use, doesn't have a problem with, say, changing the type of a field or the cardinality of a relationship.

This isn't even in the Temporary Limitations section of that web page.

Why is this limitation here and what am I supposed to do when I make a mistake when defining a type? Delete the whole database and import all the data into a new one?